# Selecting/Searching from a Collection

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I need to search if a certain item exists inside a collection. I am aware of the EXISTS function but it only returns true if a certain index is occupied and not if an item is inside that collection.

I have the following type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Person AS OBJECT (
    ID NUMBER(12, 0),
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_TYPES AS
    TYPE PersonTable IS TABLE OF Person;
END MYTYPES;
```

I then try the following:

```
DECLARE
    v_Row PERSON := PERSON(NULL, NULL, NULL);
    v_Table MYTYPES.PersonTable := MYTYPES.PersonTable();
BEGIN
    SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME INTO v_Row FROM TABLE(v_Table);
END;
```

but receives the following error:

```
ORA-06550
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL Statements.
```

I also tried:

```
DECLARE
    v_Row PERSON := PERSON(NULL, NULL, NULL);
    v_Table MYTYPES.PersonTable := MYTYPES.PersonTable();
BEGIN
    SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME INTO v_Row FROM TABLE(CAST(v_Table AS MYTYPES.PersonTable));
END;
```

but also receives an error:

```
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `select` statement belongs to `SQL`, not `PL/SQL`, you need to declare `PersonTable` type at database level like `Person` type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Person AS OBJECT (
    ID NUMBER(12, 0),
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(100)
);

/

create or replace TYPE PersonTable IS TABLE OF Person;
/
```

Then you can use it as desired:

```
DECLARE
    v_Row PERSON; 
    v_Table PersonTable;
BEGIN

    select Person(1 , 'a' , 'b' )
    bulk collect into v_Table
    from dual;


    SELECT Person(ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) INTO v_Row 
    FROM TABLE(v_Table);

END;
```

Illustrated by [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75958/8).